# Android Alpha Tests : "The requested URL was not found on this server" or "item not found"

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I published an alpha version of my game on the android play store to test it. As in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718540/android-alpha-testing-item-not-found), everything seems to be fine BUT I cannot access the alpha play store page to download the apk. 
I followed every solutions I can find on forums (clear cache, keep only one account on my phone, etc) but still no positives results.
The alpha is in published state since 1 week.

Has anyone encountered similar delays/issues ? and if so have you found any solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. After contacting Google (and spending a lot of time looking for a solution) they gave me the right place to look for :

The application was released under a company developer account and we didn't remove the (already checked) "Limited distribution" option you can find in the google play console under the pricing tab.

Everything works perfectly now !