# Google App is Published on Internal Test Track but Can't Be Found/Downloaded

Tags: android, google-play, publish, google-play-console, rollout

I've successfully completed the publishing process for an APK to the Internal Test Track.
But when I try to view the App for download on the Google Play Store using the "VIEW ON GOOGLE PLAY" link in the screenshot below...

[image]

...it opens a new window with the following error:
[image]

I've also tried using the testers link "download it on Google Play." below...
[image]

...but it results in the same message stating the App can't be found.

This is the first time the App has been published and it's being done on the Internal Test Track.
[image]

The automated testing picked up a few warning and minor issues but no errors:
[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  I've contacted Google support for advice but I thought it would be worth trying here too and seeing if anyone had any suggestions on what to try next.
Thanks.

Comment: Google Play Console > Release > Internal App Sharing > Select "Anyone you shared the link with can download" - even though I was already on the list, this is what made it work `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If this is the first time your app is being published on a track, it will take a couple of hours to be processed. This is only a one-time thing though, for future updates, the availability will be immediate on the internal test track.

Once the app is available, you'll also need to follow the opt-in link to be eligible for the download of the app.

[image: Opt-in link]

Comment: Thanks!  The App was online for over 24 hours when I was experiencing the issue.  But I did as advised and send the opt-in link to my tester user and this time it went to a summary page which DID link to a working store page.  I also promoted the App from Internal to Closed but I don't know if that was a factor, I only mention it in case someone else see's this solution and the opt in link alone doesn't work for them.

Comment: Ah so it takes *time* for this link to show up! I swear there is no mention of that on the portal, it seems like an instant thing, no wonder I was confused/thought I had made a mistake!

Comment: @JMK, how long it takes for this link to show up? I am now googling all over the place to understand why it is not showing up for me...

Comment: @HX_unbanned IIRC it took a day or two, was convinced I had done something wrong initially but it showed up eventually.

Comment: @JMK , thanks. Lets hope it happens to me as well :)

Comment: Isn't this something that should be 'fixed' by Google by now because this clearly doesn't seem to be the right functionality i-e linking users to a 'page not found' address.

Comment: what if the opt-in url doesn't appear because the app is not published? what do you have to do to publish it when the internal test is already published?

Comment: The internal test track is only available to apps already published in the store.

Comment: It was available for me even though I never published the app. After a lot of searching I realized that the app is pending for publishing. Although I was never informed of this, it is possible to see in the app's dashboard.So even that the internal test version is "launched" (not sure about the English word used), it might not be published and might be pending and you are not informed. Then go to the dashboard (or overview) of the app. It is linked on the left menu above Statistics. In the dashboard, at the top, where the app and logo are displayed, it says if it is pending for publishing.

Comment: How we can get to know that the app is available?

Comment: It took me 4 days to get this in a published state. Google has really changed it's methodology.

Comment: I have the same issue now and I was wondering if i do something wrong. But the status is in the dashboard togehter with an information at the top that the app is still in check. A link leads to this explanation: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282
So seems to be ok. I'm waiting for a status change now...

Comment: For me (or now) it said that it can take up to 48hours

Comment: @Pierre yes the internal-test track cannot be used unless the store listing is live. i.e. one has to wait until the app is published live at-least once..

Comment: what on earth. the 'only applies to already published app' is such a crucial piece of info that needs to be made more obvious!

Comment: If the internal test option is only available to already published apps why google is letting me use the internal test option! This is crucial! I was looking into this for over two hours! Google a multi billion company cant use child logic to help developers do their job. Unbelievable situation!

Comment: Is that true? You can only internally test an already published app? That makes little (well, no) sense?

Comment: This has not been my experience -- it can take several hours for an update to appear on devices even after using the test track for many months.

Comment: @Meekohi This question is not about an open or closed track but about the _internal_ test track.

Comment: Correct, I am referring to the internal test track.

Comment: Consider reaching out to Play Developer support if you're seeing a different behaviour.

Comment: According to the Google support contact us flow "...our support specialists won't be able to help you fix this problem. Please try one of the solutions given previously."

Comment: What have you tried? Was it your first upload? How long did you wait? It looks like this has worked for most people so I assume there is something different to your case and if so you may want to consider creating another post with the details of the symptoms and what you've tried for the best answer.

Comment: An internal test track is different than internal app sharing. People are really confused here. No, internal test tracks do not require a published / released version of the app.

Comment: This is so frustrating. Why would an app need to be published before it can be internally tested? Why is there no indication of an error? It simply doesn't work. But having built many Google integrations -- OAuth, YouTube, apps -- that's what I've come to expect from Google: Bad docs, no support, good luck.

Comment: FYI - it just started working after a weekend, APK submitted Wednesday 12/9, not working Friday, working Monday 12/14. So 3-5 days for me. It also didn't download on the device directly, but the link works from Google Play on desktop -> install to device.

Comment: So to conclude...does the app need to be published or not? i have created an open testing track...but am getting the same issue as the screenshot. The play store seriously sucks, it has been the worst part of my mobile app journey.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I've got status "active" on the internal test track since Monday, now it's Sunday and app still cannot be downloaded for testing. I tried with Play app and desktop browser. Same is true, by the way, for pre-registration - says it's active, but nothing there. What's the point of testing and pre-reg if you need a published production version?! Not happy.

Comment: They have this small notice in manuals: "Note: If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up to 48 hours for your app's internal test to be available."

Comment: Just to add another voice to the choir: I'm struggling with the same problem right now and so far, none of the suggested solutions work. Google really sucks, wrong or outdated docs, confusing instructions scattered all over the web. If I didn't have to, I'd trash the Android version of my app immediately.

Comment: This used to work flawlessly for me, but after changing artifact from apk to app-bundle, I can only download the latest apk-app from 'internal track'. I have tried to do a "clean the track", by creating a release with no artifacts (this is because version-code for apk is like "400123" (for x64) while only 123 for app-bundle). I tried unsubscribing and re-subscribing to the 'internal track'. Deleted my Google-id email from "testers". Cleared Google Play cache on device. Tried installing from web - but here only the newest apk-version is available (which is at least consistent).

Comment: This solution worked for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAiu76l4-7s

Comment: @Chefk5 solution works ie Google Play Console > Release > Internal App Sharing > Select "Anyone you shared the link with can download"

Comment: @Pierre not it's not, I have been testing and using a non-published app from the internal testing track all week.

Comment: By published, I mean on any track that is not "internal testing". Released on a closed track is still considered published even if it's not publicly available.

Comment: For anyone reading to here it's possible you didn't tick the mysterious tick box next to your testers list. Despite nothing being written about what it is for, apparently it enables the whole thing and is vital. Thanks to the answer below for that.

Comment: The "mysterious" tick that says "Active" just above it? ^^

Answer (score 102):

Please delete cache and data of google play app on your device, then new updated version will be available

Comment: For those of us not used to having to manage the cache of installed applications manually: This varies by device/OS version but some combinations of: Apps → Settings → Device (if displayed) → Apps/Applications/App Manager/Application Manager → Shows list of all apps installed → Google Play Store → Storage (if displayed) → Clear Cache/Clear Data (or search Google for your specific device)

Comment: I have to do this every time I use a new internal test version of another package name. Seriously..

Comment: If you have followed the steps in the accepted answer, this is most likely what will solve it for you

Comment: Since the acceptance answer has a million comments, I'll add one here to give weight to this answer: @barbie's suggestion **_worked_** for me to get rid of spinner (even if it was to get "not found" instead — that's better than interminable blank screen spinner). I still can't believe manual data & cache delete is needed though.

Answer (score 42):

**For Android App Bundles (AAB)**

[image: Version Not Found]

1. On the left menu, select Release > Devices and versions > App bundle
   explorer.
2. Select the artifact filter near the top right of the page.
3. On the “Choose an artifact” table, select the right arrow on the
   artifact you want to view.
4. Select the Downloads tab.
5. To share a link to install a specific APK: In the “Internal app
   sharing link” section, select Copy shareable link.

As of today, the format of the shareable link:

```
https://play.google.com/apps/test/<package.name>/<version.number>
```

---

**For Both APKs and AABs**

You can use **Internal app sharing** instead.

Upload an APK or app bundle on the [internal app sharing upload page](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing/)
Then you can make your app available to anyone by sharing a download link.

Before anyone can download, they need to turn on internal app sharing on their Google Play Store app.

- Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
- Tap Menu Menu > Settings.
- In the “About” section, tap the Play Store version 7 times.
- After the Internal app sharing setting appears, tap the switch to turn on
  internal app sharing.

More information can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en).

Comment: I'm getting the error: "The app '<appname>' needs to be published before you can use internal app sharing." :( Kinda defeats the whole point for it

Comment: @DShook Maybe your package name is invalid. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594516/3647002

Comment: This works great, thanks so much. One note to people who have multiple Google Accounts. Make sure on Google Play Store you are logged into to the one that you selected when uploading the bundle/APK. If you dont you will get an infinite loading spinner.

Comment: I found that the user also has to uninstall the publicly available version of your app from their phone before it allows install from the shareable link. Also needed to set permission according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205627/536625

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response!!!!

Answer (score 30):

Answer for latest play console 2021
I was having same problem but since play console is lot different I didnt found any suitable solution but after trying a bit, this was solution that worked for me.

Play Console > Setup > Internal App Sharing > Email Lists > Make sure your email list is checked and saved.

In uploader and tester section make sure 'Anyone you shared link with can download' is selected.

Thats it.

I also created video on how this problem can be solved:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAiu76l4-7s

[image: screenshot of Email list permission]

Comment: THIS was it! The old console was bad. The new console is worse. So unclear. Note: I also had to make the app NOT DEBUGGABLE.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the solution. They could not have designed it worse.

Comment: This worked for me. The "internal app sharing" link didn't work until I set these permissions. Create such a link via this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205627/536625

Comment: For god's sake! That was it! What the hell is that tick for? It's just a tick box with nothing written next to it or anything, god knows what it's for but apparently it is crucial. At the very least it should be ticked by default ffs.

Answer (score 22):

I just went through this completely unintuitive process, so let me clear up some myths:

1. Internal testing does NOT require the app be publicly released
2. The review process for your app apparently needs to complete before the app is available, as others pointed out, but the Play Console gives no indication this is a prerequisite, and happily states in several places that the App is available to internal testers when it is not. In my case the review took about a month to complete, which is why the "We are experiencing longer than normal review times" message was appearing in the console. This was the initial creation of my app, so I don't know which items-under-review were actually required, as the whole backlog completed at the same time (also with no notice to me).
3. Even at this point, if I follow the 'join' link on my phone, I still have the same issues the OP had. Clearing Play Store cache and other tricks did nothing. Instead, I had to click it from a PC, follow the prompts, and choose to install to a specific device (which requires the 7-tap developer mode on the device mentioned by others)

Comment: A MONTH!! Wow. I would say this is an edge case as the longest review time i've personally ever experienced is ~24 hours and typically less.

Comment: The review process is **not required** for Internal testing tracks. You just upload it, without descriptions, screenshots, nor answering the 700 questions for public apps, and it's ready to be installed on any device/emulator. Also, make sure to add the users to the Testers list, otherwise the store won't show the app (even with the invite link - it is for inviting members of your list exclusively).

Answer (score 16):

My case, hope it help. (Internal testing)

Make sure:

1. Change your version code for new release.
2. Add tester emails.

After upload and share link, must do these steps to download:

1. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
2. Click the Menu icon Menu > Settings.
3. In the "About" section, tap the Play Store version 7 times.
4. Once the Internal App Sharing setting appears, tap the switch to enable internal app sharing.
5. Click Enable.

Hours on this.

[image]

Comment: To do item 4 above, for Android 14,  select `Settings > General > Developer options > Internal app sharing` (toggle option)

Answer (score 7):

In my case the missing step was to enable Managed Google Play, which "Manage your private app and make it available to specific organisations". You don't need to apply an organisation filter, and simply use the internal test tracks.

The setting is found in Setup > Advanced Settings > Managed Google Play

[image: Play Store Admin]

Comment: I think your solution is about closed testing tracks and question is about internal testing tracks. Closed != Internal and your anwser that you can simply use "internal test tracks" is a bit confusing when compared to what is available in those Managed Google Play settings. Even on the screenshot you can see it says "closed testing tracks". Or the case is that closed tracks settings influence internal settings, that wouldn't be a total surprise ;-)

Comment: Careful with this - we just went to production and no one could see it due to this Managed By Google Play setting (which we definitely didn't select). In Setup > Advanced Settings > Managed By Google play you need to UNcheck your org for it to be publicly available!

Comment: Now remove option is removed too! WARNING ***WE NEED TO CREATE A NEW APP IF WE ACCIDENTALLY ENABLE MANAGED GOOGLE PLAY - YUK!***

Comment: That sounds concerning. However, I just checked our app which is has "Managed" turned on, and we can still turn it off. I'm interested to see if other people have lost the ability to disable it too?

Comment: No, be careful. Don't turn it on. This is totally a different thing. And If you enabled it you won't be able to revert that.

Answer (score 2):

@pierre was right. But that was some time ago, and now that link is not called `Opt-in URL`, but `Join on the web`. Just ask your testers to open it before they download the application.
[image: -]

Comment: This worked for me. It seems that the tester email address needs to be "confirmed" but I didn't get an email when I set it up so I guess you need to go to this link to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that of the version `X.Y.Z`, Google Play Console uses `Z` to determine the newest version of the app. So if, for example, the previous version of your app was `1.70.170`, then `2.1.171` would work, but `2.1.1` would not show up for you as it would be considered older than `1.70.170`.

Comment: Version name does not manage order at console, that would be version code. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning

Comment: @VictorR.Oliveira correct, we use the `Z` as our `versionCode`.

Comment: You save the day @TaylorKline, thank you really much !

Answer (score 1):

We just had a related issue in this completely horrible process - documenting here because it burned a week for us.

**Problem:** We got approved on closed and production 2x but no one could see our app in internal, closed, public test tracks or on the public store.

**How it happens:** As far as I can tell when you start a Closed Test Track an organization gets auto-selected on `Setup > Advanced Settings > Managed By Google` and/or you can (irreparably!) set one yourself on the `Closed Testing` page. This means that only people in your org will be able to access it.

**Solution:** If Internal/Closed/Production is not showing up the solution may be: In `Setup > Advanced Settings > Managed By Google` you UN-check your org for it to be publicly available, as in the helpful alert in the screenshot below.

[image: Google Play unchecking Managed By Google makes it public]

Duh. Worst default ever? :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, i clicked the link play console gave me on phone

```
https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/***********
```

But it didn't work, i clicked the link with pc, got the play store link, and clicked link on phone, and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

We wasted three days just to find out that the App was unpublished in

`Setup > Advanced settings > App availability`

After changing this, it took them a few hours to show the internal test track app in the store.

Ridiculous, because we initially enabled this setting because it was automatically shown in the (public) Play Store and we didn't want it to appear yet.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the application from google play store link will be available on internal testing page inside.

Click on Internal testing

[image]

**Step 1:** Click **copy link** and use any browser

**Step 2:** after that it will show **Accept Invitation** already you are opened your added mail id from the google play developer console for internal tester on this application.

**Step 3:** [image]

finally click on **download it on google play**

thats all. enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

##### Before you try all other helpful solutions here:

try this first: Search in google play store with quotation mark around your app_name like this `"app_name"`

Answer (score -4):

Go to settings --> then internal app testing and add your testers there. Follow the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAiu76l4-7s