# You don’t have permission to use internal app sharing for your app

Tags: android

I am trying to upload an APK for internal app sharing from play store, but while uploading it, its giving me following error:
You don’t have permission to use internal app sharing for com.example

Do we need to add privacy policy prior to it? My app is not using any permission except Internet and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. Please tell me why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to add a privacy policy prior to it. I would suggest checking a couple of things:

1. That you are an authorized uploader for internal app sharing. You can check this under development tools > internal app sharing > manage uploaders in the google play console.
2. That you are using one of ***your*** published application IDs in the Google Play Console. For instance, if you're trying to upload somebody else's sample app to internal app sharing in your console, you should go and change the applicationID in your build.gradle to your published application ID.

Seems like (2) is most likely your issue considering your application id is most likely *not* com.example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Along with what Sonia said, number 2 was somewhat my issue because google play wasn't aware of my package name yet.  This was a new app and I hadn't published any apk yet.  I first had to publish and apk before the Internal App Sharing would allow me to upload the same apk.

Comment: So I cannot test a debug build with `applicationIdSuffix ".dev"`?

Comment: @Entreco exactly my question. I wanted to test in-app updates feature and now it turns out I can't upload by debug build which is suffixed with a .dev

Comment: I have published an app in Closed track. It is downloadable in the closed track. Now I am uploading the same app in Internal app sharing but I am told that I don't have permission to use internal app sharing for 'package_name'.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you also need to be signed into Chrome with your developer account.

I was getting this message when logging in with multiple Google accounts (e.g. the url was `https://play.google.com/console/u/3/internal-app-sharing`). Logging into a new Chrome session with just my developer account has it working properly (url does not contain `u/3/`).

Comment: It worked at last! Thanks so much for sharing this tip!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious issues discussed in the previous answers, you can work around this issue by temporarily removing the suffix from your `buildType` in your `app` module's `gradle.build`

For example: comment out the `applicationIdSuffix ".dev"` or `".staging"`, then generate an app bundle, so you end up with a `dev` or `staging` build but the `applicationId` is that of the `release` build.

Now upload the app bundle to internal app sharing with no problem, even if it is debuggable + minified.

Comment: My app certificate signatures were different for the different build types, so just commenting out the `applicationIdSuffix` did not work for me. Had to upload the prod build type eventually.