# Test In-app review in android mobile application

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

I have implemented Google Play In-App Review in my android application. but not understanding how to test it. I have gone through google API documentation it's written there you can test via internal app sharing. But when I am uploading my signed .abb or .apk file in Google Play Console Internal app sharing it gives an error like: You don't have permission to use internal app sharing for..... Package Name.

Below is my code which I have added for In-App Review. Please check that also:

```
final ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
        request.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ReviewInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ReviewInfo> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // We can get the ReviewInfo object
                    ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
                    Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(dashboardActivity.this, reviewInfo);
                    flow.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                            // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no
                            // matter the result, we continue our app flow.
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // There was some problem, continue regardless of the result.
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57442473/9134576) helps you?

Comment: Hi there. did you found any solution for testing?