# URL not found on Google Play app when signed in as internal app tester

Tags: android, google-play, apk, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to publish a PWA on the Google Play store, and coming up against some confusing problems testing as an internal app. I used [PWA2APK](https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/) to convert my PWA to an APK. There are not major issues found through the pre-launch report, and only one accessibility warning. The project passed all of the requirements for the Play Store in December. I am the only user on the internal app testing list, and I receive an error message when attempting to install on Android through the internal app testing link. When I hover over the info symbol beside the project, I get this pop up:
[image: error message for Google Play Project dashboard]

> Only testers can view this listing on Google Play because you haven't
>   uploaded any APKs to Production yet.

However, I posted an APK to Internal Tests on December 17, 2019. 
[image: internal test console]

When I click the View on Google Play link I'm taken to a URL not found page with the text:

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

When I use the internal testing link to download the app on the play store on my mobile, I get a page with the app logo, title, and developer name, as well as the price on the download button. When I click the button I get an error message:

> Error 
>   The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

I have checked out the advice on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896956/google-app-is-published-on-internal-test-track-but-cant-be-found-downloaded), but am still having problems. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: having the same problem

Comment: Did it eventually work out for you?

Comment: @BrunoBieri - The testing link works through the new dashboard, but still shows an error 400 when I use the original testing link. Overall I find the setup for internal testing on the new dashboard even more confusing, but the links do seem to work when I add people to the email list.

Comment: It took time, but came online later.

Comment: Check if you did right way of adding email https://stackoverflow.com/a/66192742/11888809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ShabbirAhmed mentioned, it likely just requires waiting for the **IARC Content Ratings** to be accepted. However, in my experience you will also need to access the link through the most recent dashboard system, and not through links provided prior to April 2020 (at least). I will update if any new info comes up from Google Play.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still running into this, make sure to go to Setup -> Internal App Sharing and accept the terms. The Play Store link started working instantly after doing so.

Comment: Thank you - this was what I was missing.

Comment: Exactly the problem and fix for me :) Thank you

Comment: There are no terms to accept. Only a toggle button is available to enable it. I followed this process: Go to play store app -> activated developer mode by clicking play store version 7 times -> Go to general -> enable internal app sharing.

Comment: I have selected my app, but I don't see Settings -> Internal App Sharing in the left nav. Can someone describe how to navigate to that?

Comment: Ah, I found it! It is Setup -> Internal App Sharing now, not Settings.

Comment: I can't find it neither in the phone or the web. Could you guys update the answer with a link and/or screenshots? THanks @MarkVolkmann

Comment: @titusfx I believe they are mentioning the play store setting, which is hidden until you enable "developer mode". Go to play store settings, find the about section and tap seven times on the version number to enable it.

Here's a guide with screenshots: https://hankli0130.medium.com/how-to-share-your-app-using-internal-testing-on-google-play-646b1ab1b414

Answer (score 14):

May be your **IARC Content Ratings** has not been accepted yet. Just wait for one or two more days. It will be accepted and app will be available on play store. If it doesn't create a new IARC Ratings.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 404 when I am not logged into Google services on the phone using the same email address as entered for me in the list of internal testers.

I see the something similar when I go to the link using a desktop browser. If I am signed into Google services I get a message saying to open the link on an Android device. But if I click the link when not signed in, I get a 404.

I think this is a form of security to stop the link from being shared with people that are not testers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait a couple of business days for IARC ratings.