# Google Play internal test track not available, despite saying it's active

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I've just uploaded my very first Android build (.aab) to Google Play and wish to test it on the "internal" test track. It says the internal test track is "Active", but I'm getting this error when I click the shareable test link:

[image: Can't find the app]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is where the track is showing as "Active" and where I'm copying the shareable test link from:

[image: Internal test track]

I'd also like to mention that the internal test track didn't become active until Google reviewed and approved the app, which took a few days. Why does Google need to approve the app for internal testing?

Comment: I hope you are added as a tester in the Internal test release program.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be.

65

If this is the first time your app is being published on a track, it will take a couple of hours to be processed. This is only a one-time thing though, for future updates, the availability will be immediate on the internal test track.

Once the app is available, you'll also need to follow the opt-in link to be eligible for the download of the app.

Comment: Can I ask where did you extract the shareable link from? Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: Ah ok. Anyway, as I mentioned I'm added as a tester, so that shouldn't be the problem. I've also added a number of other internal tester email addresses and they can't seem to access the link either. I extracted the link from "Internal Testing > Testers > Copy link" (this is in the latest Google Play Console UI).

Comment: Yeah. You should open on your phone with the right login email to play store. Usually it doesn't take more than 45 minutes

Comment: Then there's definitely something wrong. The builds have been up there for a few days.

Comment: The internal test track is only available to apps already published in the store

Comment: So we're not supposed to test our apps before publishing them the first time? That makes no sense. Could you please link to the Google documentation that states that?

Comment: Came across this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896956/google-app-is-published-on-internal-test-track-but-cant-be-found-downloaded

Comment: It doesn't seem to be clear on that post either. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896956/google-app-is-published-on-internal-test-track-but-cant-be-found-downloaded#comment115181177_53898812