# How to Install Old version builds from Google Play Internal Testing?

Tags: android, testflight, google-play-internal-testing

TestFlight provides a way to download and install the old builds. Is there a similar functionality offered in Google Play internal testing. We have a situation where we need to download and install a old version of the app released through Google Play internal testing.[image]

Comment: Have you seen/tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63205627/295004

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @MorrisonChang saved my life. Why does Google make everything so complicated....