# Google Play Doesn't Show App: 'We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.'

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have published two apps on Google Play Store: `App-1` and `App-2`

`App-1` pressing 'View on Google Play' shows it normally.
However, `App-2` pressing 'View on Google Play' shows: ***We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.***

*Following are some information and screenshots from Google Play Console for both the apps:*

`App-1` **WORKING AS INTENDED**:

- Received IARC Content Ratings Notice mail within 5 days
- Shows available on Google Play
- Can be searched and found on Google Play by anyone and everyone
- Internal testers can test through testing link

> `App-1` Release overview:
>
> [image: app-1 release overview]

> `App-1` Dashboard:
>
> [image: app-1 dashboard]

> `App-1` when pressing 'View on Google Play':
>
> [image: app-1 google play]

`App-2` **NOT WORKING AS INTENDED**:

- Did not receive IARC Content Ratings Notice mail (it has been 12 days)
- Shows available on Google Play
- Cannot be searched and found on Google Play by *developer account* or normal users
- Internal testers cannot test through testing link
- Can be searched and found on Google Play by the *admin account* only

> `App-2` Release overview (originally published on 18th September 2023):
>
> [image: app-2 release overview]

> `App-2` Dashboard:
>
> [image: app-2 dashboard]

> `App-2` when pressing 'View on Google Play':
>
> [image: app-2 google play]

> `App-2` when pressing 'View on Google Play' from ADMIN ACCOUNT:
>
> [image: app-2 google play admin]

***May I know if it's because of the IARC Content Ratings or if there's anything else that I missed.***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896956/google-app-is-published-on-internal-test-track-but-cant-be-found-downloaded?rq=2 this may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The issue was I released the app as private app by accident.

Google Support helped me out to delete my app and re-release a new one.